# How to reconstruct single object after its deconstruction in jq

Tags: json, object, jq

I receive a quite big json file with lots of properties that are there only for historical reasons and are not used anymore. To simplify this file, I've used `jq`, deconstructed json with `to_entries`, but now I don't know how to rebuild my object back with sub-objects that remained.

Here's example:

input

```
{
  "empty1": [],
  "empty2": [],
  "full1": "test",
  "full2": { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
}
```

current filter:

```
to_entries[] | select((.value | length) > 0) | { (.key) : .value }
```

current output

```
{"full1":"test"}
{"full2":{"a":1,"b":2}}
```

desired output

```
{
  "full1": "test",
  "full2": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the full command you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `with_entries()` is much shorter, with which you can just do

```
jq 'with_entries(select((.value | length) > 0))' json
```

For your question, `from_entries` does the opposite conversion of `to_entries`. And using `with_entries(foo)` is a shorthand for `to_entries | map(foo) | from_entries` syntax.

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason this does not work at jqplay.org (while `to_entries | map( select((.value | length) > 0) ) | from_entries` does). However when I tried this locally it did work. Thank you.